# AngularJS: Shift Focus to the Next TextBox using Enter Key

Tags: angularjs

I have a form with multiple fields. When I open the form, by default the first field should be set to focus. When I press enter key it has to move to next textbox. I have tried the below code default focus is working but enter key is not working.

```
app.directive('focus',function($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope : {
                trigger : '@focus'
            },
            link : function(scope, elem,attrs) {
                scope.$watch('trigger', function(value) {
                    if (value === "true") {
                        $timeout(function() {
                            elem[0].focus();
                        });                         
                    }                           
                });
                elem.bind('keydown', function(e) {
                    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
                    if (code === 13) {
                      e.preventDefault();
                      elem.next().focus();
                    }
                  });
            }
        };
    });
```

**HTML**

```
    <input type='text'  class='form-control'  focus='true'/>
    <input type='text'  class='form-control'  focus='true'/>
    <input type='text'  class='form-control'  focus='true'/>
```

Comment: Why is the `elem.bind` inside the `scope.$watch`? Is it necessary? And does the callback inside `elem.bind` being called at all?

Comment: Thanks for reply. It is not neccessary. I just tried. Even it is not working.

Comment: Try to place a `elem.on('keydown', function() { console.log(arguments); });` outside the `scope.$watch` and check if it's being triggered. Otherwise, place a `console.log(elem)` and check if the element inside the directive is the same as the element in the final rendered DOM.

Comment: It is triggered, and Log is printed.

Comment: Ok, so now you have your event, does the `elem.next()` returns the correct element? If it's being triggered, your code should work now, it seems correct.

Comment: No, it is directly hitting the submit button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84338/discussion-between-n123-and-mrodrigues).

Comment: Oh, I see. This is weird, I have a similar directive and the `event.preventDefault()` does the trick. The submit button is being hit before or after this callback's being run? The `elem.next()` returns the correct element?